# Check for String containing letters to return -1 in Swift command line app

Tags: swift, string

I have been at this for hours and can't work it out, please help. I am doing some coding practice to help sharpen up my skills in swift and this one seems so easy but I can't work it out.

I need to create a simple function that returns (the challenge i'm doing asks for this I haven't made it up) the sum of numbers as a string, but if the string contains characters, not numbers, it should return -1. It says : Receive two values of type string. Add them together. If an input is a character, return -1

This is where I am up to but i can't get it pass the tests for returning -1. It passes 3 / 5 tests where it's fine with numbers, but not with the characters. My thinking is that the character set line should check for if myNewString contains any of those characters it should return -1

```swift
func addStrNums(_ num1: String, _ num2: String) -> String {
    // write your code here
    
    var op1 = num1
    var op2 = num2
    
    var total: Int = 0  
    
    var myNewInt = Int(op1) ?? 0
    var myNewInt2 = Int(op2) ?? 0
        
    total = myNewInt + myNewInt2
        
    var myNewString = String (total)
    
    let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn:
       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@£$%^&*()_-=+;/?><"
    )
    if myNewString.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset) != nil {
       return "-1" 
    }   
    
    return myNewString
}
```

Results of above is :

```
 Test Passed: 10 == 10
 FAILED: Expected: -1, instead got: 5
 Test Passed: 1 == 1
 Test Passed: 3 == 3
```

Comment: Might show `addStrNums()` calls? Also, `myNewString` shouldn't always have numbers since you do `String(total)` and total is a Int? (except maybe for negative values)?

Comment: thank you for replying :) as i understand it the return must be a string, so i converted from strings to ints back to a string for the return, then when i run it the thing passes in test data which might include characters, which should give a return of -1

Comment: I stopped doing the ```if myNewString``` bit and did ```if op1... and else if op2....``` and it worked that way! I guess so it could check both inputs - sorry for asking the question now :/

Comment: If you have a test that failed, it would be useful to see the test input that failed. And perhaps share the full text of the programming question next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import foundation

func addStringNumber(_ num1: String, num2: String) -> String {
    if !CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: num1)) {
        return "-1"
    }
    
    if !CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: num2)) {
        return ""
    }
    
    let sum = String.init(format: "%d", Int((num1 as NSString).intValue + (num2 as NSString).intValue))
        
    return sum
}
```

Note:- for this import foundation is important.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are using `nil` coalescing operator (`??`), which effectively says that you want to ignore errors parsing the integers. I would suggest that you want to detect those errors. E.g.

   ```swift
   func addStrNums(_ num1: String, _ num2: String) -> String {
       guard 
           let value1 = Int(num1),
           let value2 = Int(num2)
       else {
           return "-1"
       }

       let total = value1 + value2

       return "\(total)"
   }
   ```

   The initializer for `Int` will automatically fail if there are non-numeric characters.
2. These programming tests generally don’t worry about localization concerns, but in a real app, we would almost never use this `Int` string-to-integer conversion (because we want to honor the localization settings of the user’s device). For this reason, we would generally prefer `NumberFormatter` in real apps for users with different locales:

   ```swift
   let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
       let formatter = NumberFormatter()
       formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
       return formatter
   }()

   func addStrNums(_ num1: String, _ num2: String) -> String {
       guard 
           let value1 = formatter.number(from: num1)?.intValue, // use `doubleValue` if you want to handle floating point numbers, too
           let value2 = formatter.number(from: num2)?.intValue
       else {
           return "-1"
       }

       let total = value1 + value2

       return formatter.string(for: total) ?? "-1"
   }
   ```

   This accepts input that includes thousands separators and formats the output accordingly. (Obviously, feel free to use whatever `numberStyle` you want.)

   Also, be aware that `NumberFormatter` is more tolerant of whitespace before or after the digits. It also allows for a wider array of numeric characters, e.g. it recognizes “５”, a digit entered with Japanese keyboard, which is different than the standard ASCII “5”. This greater flexibility is important in a real app, but I don’t know what your programming exercise is requiring.
3. While the above demonstrates that you don’t have to check for non-numeric digits manually, you can if you need to. But you need to check the two input strings, not the string representation of the total (especially if you used `nil` coalescing operator to disregard errors when converting the strings to integers, as I discussed in point 1 above).
4. If you do this, though, I would not advise trying list all of the non-numeric characters yourself. Instead, use the `inverted` set:

   ```swift
   let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted // check for 0-9 if using `Int` To convert, use `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` if converting with `NumberFormatter`

   guard 
       num1.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) == nil,
       num2.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) == nil
   else {
       return "-1"
   }
   ```

   Or, one could use regex to confirm that there are only one or more digits (`\d+`) between the start of the string (`^`) and the end of the string (`$`):

   ```swift
   guard 
       num1.range(of: #"^\d+$"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil, // or `#"^-?\d+$"#` if you want to accept negative values, too
       num2.range(of: #"^\d+$"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
   else {
       return "-1"
   }
   ```

   FWIW, if you’re not familiar with it, the `#"..."#` syntax employs “extended string delimiters” (saving us from having to to escape the `\` characters within the string).
5. As an aside, you mentioned a command line app that should return `-1`. Generally when we talk about command line apps returning values, we’re exiting with a numeric value not a string. I would be inclined to make this function return an `Int?`, i.e. either the numeric sum or `nil` on failure. But without seeing the particulars on your coding test, it is hard to be more specific.